# Combine && and || on javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to say if URL has 'admin/deals' and 'edit' at the same time in the current url page **OR** if it contains 'deals/new', then DO something.

```
if (  (window.location.href.indexOf('admin/deals') > -1) 
            && (window.location.href.indexOf('edit') > -1) ) )
|| if (window.location.href.indexOf('deals/new') > -1){
           alert("your url contains the name franky");
      }
```

But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'
```

Comment: You can't have the keyword `if` inside an expression, remove it and I think wrap the entire thing in parentesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an `if` expression inside of another `if` expression. Try this:

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf('admin/deals') > -1 && window.location.href.indexOf('edit') > -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf('deals/new') > -1)){
    alert("your url contains the name franky");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the syntax is:

```
if (condition) || (condition)
                 ^---no "if" here
```

so

```
if ((a && b) || (c && d)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two if's - you just combine all your conditions into one if and add as many && and || as you need.

You should also ensure for every open `(` there is a closing `)`

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf('admin/deals') > -1 && 
        window.location.href.indexOf('edit') > -1 || 
        window.location.href.indexOf('deals/new') > -1) {
        alert("your url contains the name franky");
    }
```

And you might want to introduce a variable for window.location.href
like `var currentLocation = window.location.href;`
and then use that variable ...